# Tengo un input el cual tiene una tabla con varios datos, como si fuera un select. Son 104 datos, como hago para automatizar todos esos datos?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente :

```
if (sheet.getRow(1).getCell(9).toString().contentEquals("AGENTES DE VENTAS Y REPRESENTANTES DE FABRICA")) {

    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mainContent_OcupacionComboBox_B-1Img")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mainContent_OcupacionComboBox_DDD_L_LBI"+n+"T0")).click();

}

else 

if (sheet.getRow(1).getCell(9).toString().contentEquals("AGENTES: DE SEGUROS, INMOBILIARIAS, CAMBIO Y BOLSA, SERVICIOS")) {

    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mainContent_OcupacionComboBox_B-1Img")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mainContent_OcupacionComboBox_DDD_L_LBI"+n+"T0")).click();

}
```

Con Select es mas facil de hacer , pero con input no se como hacerlo.

Adjunto los id relativo

`//table[@id='ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mainContent_OcupacionComboBox_DDD_L_LBT']/tbody/tr[104]/td`

Comment: Por favor lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y de paso checa el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), tu pregunta puede terminar cerrada pues es muy amplia, no demuestra avance o intento de tu parte, dudas claras y código avanzado.

Además, no me queda claro cual es tu objetivo, puedes añadir una imagen del input o parte del html para que sea mas facil darte respuesta.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un ciclo para hallar todos los elementos con ese id

```
boxes = driver.FindElements(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mainContent_OcupacionComboBox_B-1Img"));
comboBoxes = driver.FindElements(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mainContent_OcupacionComboBox_DDD_L_LBI"+n+"T0""));

for(int i=0; i<boxes.length; i++)
{
    boxes[i].Click();
}

for(int i=0; i<comboBoxes.length; i++)
{
    comboBoxes[i].Click();
}
```